# Execute T-SQL Only If AlwaysOn Database Is Primary

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, availability-groups, ssis, ssis-2012

Little background on the system. It is SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn Availability Group with 1 primary and 1 secondary.

I have been following this article ([SSIS with AlwaysOn](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-integration-services/bg-p/SSIS)) to make SSIS work with AlwaysOn. I have a table that records the current role of the server and a job that runs every two minutes checking if it recently failed over. The problem I am running into is the secondary only accepts readonly connections for the SSISDB and my script won't execute because of it.

Here is the script:

```
USE master;
 
DECLARE @last_role TINYINT;
SET @last_role = (
   SELECT TOP 1 [replica_role]
   FROM [dbo].[replica_role]
);
 
DECLARE @current_role TINYINT;
SET @current_role = (
   SELECT ROLE 
   FROM sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states 
   WHERE is_local = 1
);
 
IF (@last_role = 2 AND @current_role = 1)
BEGIN
    USE SSISDB;
    OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'x'
    ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
END
 
USE master;
UPDATE dbo.[replica_role] SET [replica_role] = @current_role;
```

I am confused as to why the error is happening because the `IF` statement is evaluating to false so the USE SSISDB is not getting executed. I could turn the statements into strings and use exec but I would rather not if possible. When I execute the script this is the error I get:

> The target database ('SSISDB') is in an availability group and is currently accessible
> for connections when the application intent is set to read only. For more information
> about application intent, see SQL Server Books Online.

Comment: All items in the script are compiled; you may need to put the `SSISDB` related T-SQL into a `VARCHAR(MAX)` and `sp_executesql` on it instead.

Comment: That's what I thought was going on. I could also switch the secondary to readable 'Yes' rather than 'Read only'. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [client connection role for secondary replicas](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510184.aspx) determines whether your database is always available, or only available to read-only connections, or not available at all. If you set the database to read-only connections, then your connection string has to include the parameter ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly as defined in that Books Online page.

When you try to connect to that database without specifying ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly, your query will fail.

Comment: In this case it is a job I am running on the secondary server. The solution I went with was to wrap the query within the If statement in quotes and use sp_executesql. It only executes the code if the server is primary and therefore no longer readonly.